# renaming files in a directory

Tags: ubuntu, bash, grep

I have files in a directory. The file names are constructed using a date timestamp notation, the file names are of the form:

name_YYMM.csv

I want to rename all such files using the following naming convention:

name_YYYYMM.csv

I am not sure if I can use a command line utility like grep to do this, or if I need to write a bash script to do this.

Any help on how to solve this prob will be appreciated.

I am running on Ubuntu

Comment: There are batch file renaming utilities available through the Ubuntu software centre, have you tried any of these?

Comment: I don't know how to do it without a bash script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way to do it

```
ls name* | while read a; do mv $a `echo $a | sed s/name_/name_20/`; done
```

or

```
ls name* | while read a; do mv $a $(echo $a | sed s/name_/name_20/); done
```

<sup>(since use of back-quotes is depreciated (or hard to read anyway))</sup>

it lists all files matching `name_` then for each file it finds it replaces `name_` with `name_20`. You can change 20 to 19 if you are working with files from the last millennium.

Comment: 'name' is a place holder. On my disk the files are named <name>_YYMM.csv, where <name> is an alphanumeric string.

Comment: @Takashi - If <name> does not contain any underscores (_) it's still simple. Just substitute `name_` for `_` in the above example and replace `ls name*` with `ls *.csv`

Comment: It worked! thanks. Now, ... to try to understand what kind of magic we are dealing with here ;)

Comment: It would be better to use a `for` loop without `ls`. Variables that contain filenames (and, similarly, command substitution that processes filenames) should always be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have a program or Perl script called `rename` on your system.

For the [Perl script](http://www.coogans.org/rename.txt) version:

```
rename 's/_/_20/' *_*.csv
```

For the [util-linux-ng](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux-ng/) version:

```
rename _ _20 *_*.csv
```

Or, using Bash:

```
for f in name*; do mv "$f" "${f/_/_20}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

In zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(*_[0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9].csv)' '${1}20${2}'
```

You can make the pattern less precise, e.g. `'(*_??)(??.csv)'` or even `'(*)(??).csv'` if there's no risk of other files matching.

If you don't want to use zsh, see [Dennis Williamson's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/220524/renaming-files-in-a-directory/220658#220658).